# Angular child route loading parent instead of child component

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular4-router

Am trying to navigate my Angular application based on parent child concept. 
When am loading the parent component gets loaded instead of the child but the url seems the

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  {
    path: 'solutions', component: SolutionComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'cog', component: CogComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PortfolioComponent }
];
```

When I run `solutions/cog` it redirects to `SolutionComponent` but it should load `CogComponent`

EDIT: 1

It will work when I use

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'solutions', component: SolutionComponent },
  { path: 'solutions/cog', component: CogComponent },
  { path: 'portfolio', component: PortfolioComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PortfolioComponent }
];
```

But I want it should load from above method.

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: It is not redirecting to `SolutionComponent`. It is working as expected. The way you've configured the routes, `SolutionComponent` should have a `<router-outlet>` in the HTML. Then, if you navigate to `solutions/cog`, it will show the `SolutionComponent` and the `CogComponent` in place of `router-outlet` .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
...
{
    path: 'solutions', component: SolutionComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'cog', component: CogComponent }
    ]
},
...
```

Since you have declared a `component` for the path `solutions` hence it is showing `SolutionComponent` and it will render `CogComponent` in the nested `router-outlet`

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
{
    path: 'solutions'
    children: [
        { path: 'cog', component: CogComponent },
        { path: '', component: SolutionComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]
},
...
```

The above route should work as you intended.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this ? I need to have my parent and child with component, but I'm also using my route data for breadcrumb.. So I need to have the child in the childrens of my parent with a component for the parent

Answer (score 2):

Your Second Appraoch works because Angular will load the `CogComponent` Template in the Parent Router Outlet itself. If that's what you want, then you're good to go with that approach.

But if you want to have the `SolutionComponent` as a parent to the `CogComponent`, then you'll have to add a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to the `solution.component.html`.

Here's how:

```
...

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This will tell Angular that it needs to load the `CogComponent` in there as the `/cog` is a Child Route to the `/solution` route.

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmmksw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsolution%2Fsolution.component.html) for your ref.